# why functional component is running again while using useeffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

here is my code ....shouldn't code written only in useeffect run ? why whole of my code of functional component runs ? when i run it , window alert shows up twice

here is my code :

```
const Editbookfunctionalcomponent = () => {
  let { i,isb,n } = useParams();
  window.alert(n)
  let history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const book = useSelector((state) => state.allreducers);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [isbn, setIsbn] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");

  }, [book]);

  const onUpdateContact = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const update_book = Object.assign(book, {
      name: name,
      isbn: isbn,
      image: image,
    });

    dispatch(updateBook(i,update_book));
    history.push("/")
  };
  return (
    <div className="card border-0 shadow">
     
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: In the initial render whole functional component will render and then useEffect ! and then if dependency of useEffect changes then useEffect changes will occur and do render for whole functional component !

Comment: The ENTIRE BODY of a functional component gets run *every time it re-renders*. You can think of it like the `render` function of a class component